# BlueZ: setting local address to be private and non-resolvable

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, privacy, bluez

Is there a way in BlueZ to set the Bluetooth address to be **private** and **non-resolvable** through the command line or the D-Bus API?

Currently, it is possible to enable privacy through the following sequence of commands:-

```
btmgmt power off
btmgmt privacy on
btmgmt power on
```

However, this sets the address to be **private resolvable**. In other words, remote devices that have been previously bonded with our device will be able to resolve the address and find the true identity. We would like to use a private non-resolvable address so that the identity is hidden even from previously bonded devices.

More information on different Bluetooth addresses can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241052/is-there-any-way-to-uniquely-identify-ble-device/54249172#54249172).

We are using BlueZ v5.50 on an Ubuntu machine running Linux 4.15.0-47 generic.